# Patterns for lazy default parameters in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I find myself quite often writing classes that depend on something that is potentially expensive to create, e.g. a `WebClient`. I want this dependency to be a parameter for maximum flexibility and testability.
I found the following ways of achieving this and am not sure which one to pick.

## Option A: null check in constructor

```kotlin
class MyWebAppClient(webclient: WebClient? = null) {

    private val webclient: WebClient

    init {
        this.webclient = webclient ?: generateMyWebAppClient()
    }
    ...
}
```

Usage examples:

```kotlin
MyWebAppClient()
MyWebAppClient(webclient)
```

## Option B: lambda generating the param

```kotlin
class MyWebAppClient(private val webclient: () -> WebClient = { generateMyWebAppClient()}) {
    ...
}
```

Usage examples:

```kotlin
MyWebAppClient()
MyWebAppClient({ webclient })
MyWebAppClient { webclient }
```

## Option C: initialised default param

```kotlin
class MyWebAppClient(private val webclient: WebClient = generateMyWebAppClient()) {
    ...
}
```

Usage examples:

```kotlin
MyWebAppClient()
MyWebAppClient(webclient)
```

## Question

Are there any up- or downsides to any of these approaches beyond the obvious difference in readability? Does any of these pose a risk of memory leaks, or other unexpected behaviour?

My favourite is option C, since it's the easiest to write and read. A quick test also didn't reveal any unexpected behaviour. I am just a little hesitant, because similar code in Python would call the function at the time the function is parsed, rather than at execution time.

Comment: In C `generateMyWebAppClient()` will be only called when needed, so your experience from Python does not apply here. I think this is the simplest and therefore the best approach. No need to complicate things.

Comment: Also, this is unrelated to expensive operations, but I sometimes use `null` as a default value and then replace it with true default (so similar to A, but `init {}` block is unnecessary). This is more flexible, because it makes easier to create other variants of the function with the same default value. Also, it is better for Java interop. Drawback is that the caller doesn't see what is the default value.

Answer (score 1):

Option B is lazy-loading the object and when it comes to performance this is the way to go. If you want to improve the testability, you may want to introduce `Factory` that will create your object. Employing `Factory` will not alleviate your code from the lazy-loading (if you use kotlin `Lazy`) and lambdas in constructor (readability).

```
class MyWebAppClient(private val webclientFactory: WebClientFactory) {

   private val webClient by lazy { webclientFactory.create() } 

}
```

In tests you can either provide your own test factory implementation that will return mock `WebClient` or you can just mock the `Factory` to return mock `WebClient`

Answer (score 0):

[Lazy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-lazy/) value can also be passed externally as a parameter:

```
val webClient by lazy { webclientFactory.create() }

class MyWebAppClient(private val webClientProvider: Lazy<WebClient>) {

   fun connect() = webClientProvider.value.connect()

}
```

This allows to potentially reuse single lazy value across multiple calls depending on its definition scope.